# Content-Length header ignored by IIS 6?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-headers

I'm working on a web app that includes the ability to save uploaded files.  Files are stored in a SQL database in an "image" column, and served via a GetFile.aspx page using Response.BinaryWrite().

Until yesterday I was having problems with downloading Office 2007/2010 files.  The file would download without trouble, but when Word (or Excel, or whatever Office program) opened it, it would complain about a corrupt file.  But it would still open without any immediately apparent problems or missing data.  The solution turned out to be to include a Content-Length header in the response:

```
If dr.Read() Then
  Response.Clear()
  Response.Buffer = True
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(dr("FileName").ToString()))
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", dr("ContentSize").ToString())
  Response.ContentType = dr("ContentType").ToString()
  Response.BinaryWrite(dr("FileContent"))
End If
dr.Close()
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

`dr` is a SqlDataReader.

This worked great on my local dev machine (Windows 7, IIS 7.5, ASP 2.0).  Files downloaded and opened without a problem.  But on our test server (Windows Server 2003, IIS 6), it's still an issue.  I took a look at the traffic using WireShark, and discovered that my Content-Length header wasn't present!  Everything else I am setting (including a test header: `Response.AppendHeader("TestHeader", "TestValue")` shows up.  I made sure that ContentSize has a value in the data I'm getting, and I even tried changing it to `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", "1234567")` to just get a value in there.  Nothing shows up!

I also tried Fiddler to look at the traffic; my dev machine does indeed include the content-length property (though it's apparently off by one byte...Fiddler reported a protocol violation), and the test server does not!

What's going on?  Is IIS 6 ignoring the header for some reason?  Is there a setting I need to change?

Comment: how you have stored dr("ContentSize") value? maybe actual file content length and the stored value might be different which windows server 2k3 explicitly checks.take a look at following code which sets the content length of a string eg :byte[] s = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultString);
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", s.Length.ToString());

Comment: @DSharper - it's an int in the database, and the value is obtained from the ContentLength property of HtmlInputFile.PostedFile.  As I noted in the question, Fiddler complains that it's off by one byte; are you saying that IIS 6 would ignore the header because of that?